# How to select used items in a ManyToMany Doctrine relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities (Item & Tag) linked by a bidirectional ManyToMany relation, and I'd like to display the entity (Tag) records that are actually used in a relation with the other entity (Item) :

Here is my Item entity:

```
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="items")
     */
    private $tags;
}
```

And my Tag enity :

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Item", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $items;
}
```

Now in my Tag Repository I've tried this :

```
class TagRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllUsed()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.items', 'items')
            ->groupBy('items.id')
            ->having('COUNT(t.id) > 0')
            ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't give me the result I'm expecting... Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

I didn't test but It seems your error is in the count clause. You are counting tags `having('COUNT(t.id) > 0')`. So it will return all tags.
Another error is you grouping by 'items' and selecting only 't'. You don't need group by.

**Solutions**

Change 'tags' for 'items' in having clause.

```
public function findAllUsed()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->leftJoin('t.items', 'items')            
        ->having('COUNT(items.id) > 0')
        ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Another possible way more simple is do a innerJoin like @KevinTheGreat, but check won't need having or where clauses any more:

```
public function findAllUsed()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->innerJoin('t.items', 'items')           
        ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Second solution is simple and easy! I should study a bit more my SQL language... thanks Vinicius!

Answer (score 1):

I did this from the top of my head, but it should work, I used an innerJoin instead of a leftJoin and then added a where to make sure you get the records that are linked:

```
public function findAllUsed()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->innerjoin('t.items', 'i')
            ->groupBy('i.id')
            ->where('i.id = t.items')
            ->having('COUNT(t.id) > 0')
            ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

I used this example to formulate the answer: [Query on a many-to-many relationship using Doctrine with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549120/query-on-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-doctrine-with-symfony2)

Comment: I have the error " 'items GROUP BY': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected." now.

Comment: Did you change the -groupBy('items.id') to ('i.id')

Comment: You answer is redundant a little bit. Because `where('i.id = t.items')` is already included in the inner join.